# Complexity of a string permutation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Consider the following code to permute a string containing unique characters from McDowell:

This code is based on a recursion and adds to each result by placing a character to every single spot. If the string contains n characters, then there are n+1 such places.

Since for every string (there are n! possible strings of length n), you add n+1 characters, the complexity should be 1! + 2! + ... + (n+1)!

The author says that the complexity is O(n!). Is this the same as O(1!+...+(n+1)!)? If so, why?

```
public static ArrayList<String> getPerms(String str){
    if (str == null){
      return null;
    }

    ArrayList<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (str.length() == 0){
      permutations.add("");
      return permutations;
    }

    char first = str.charAt(0);
    String remainder = str.substring(1);
    ArrayList<String> words = getPerms(remainder);
    for (String word: words){
      for (int j = 0; j <= word.length(); j++){
        String s = insertCharAt(word, first, j);
        permutations.add(s);
      }
    }
    return permutations;
  }

  public static String insertCharAt(String s, char c, int j){
    String start = s.substring(0, j);
    String end = s.substring(j+1);
    return start + c + end;
  }
```

Comment: no, `n!` is not the sum factorials up to n.

Comment: how can I prove it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define `F(n)` as the length of the list returned by `getPerms` when you pass it a string of length `n`.

By inspection of the base case, we see that `F(0) == 1`.

In the recursive case, with a string of length `n > 0`, `getPerms` calls itself recursively on a string of length `n-1`.  It gets back a list of length `F(n-1)` (that is the definition of `F`) and stores the list in `words`. For each element of `words`, it adds `n` elements to `permutations`.  Thus `permutations` will have `n * F(n-1)` elements when it is returned.

Therefore, `F(n) == n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1 == n!`.  The `getPerms` function returns a list of length `n!` given a string of length `n`.

Now, what is the *complexity* of `getPerms`?  I'll assume we're talking about time complexity.  Well, it performs ∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>i! list appends in total (n! for the outermost call, plus (n-1)! for the first recursive call, plus (n-2)! for the second recursive call, etc.).  So you could say the complexity is O(∑<sup>n</sup>i!) list appends.

But list appends aren't the only computation here.  We copy a lot of characters around when we join strings in Java.

Let's say `G(n)` is the number of character copies performed by a call to `getPerms` when you pass a string of length `n`.

By inspection of the base case, we see that `G(0) == 0`.

In the recursive case, `getPerms` calls itself on a string of length `n-1`, which performs `G(n-1)` character copies and returns a list of `F(n-1)` strings, each of length `n-1`.  Then `getPerms` copies each of those strings `n` times, inserting another character into each copy, so `F(n-1) * n * n == n * n!` characters copied directly in the `getPerms` call, in addition to the `G(n-1)` from the recursion.

Thus the number of characters copied by a call to `getPerms` is O(∑<sub>i=0</sub><sup>n</sup>i * i!).